# Installing Soap for Magento installation to work

Tags: php, magento, soap

I am trying a new installation of Magento but cannot get past the the initial setup due to SOAP not being installed.
We have a dedicated server 
CentOS 6.7 (Final)
I have tried command yum install php-soap

but get the following

```
[root@s16030606 ~]# yum install php-soap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.23media.de
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-soap.x86_64 0:5.3.3-46.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6 for package: php-soap-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-soap-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6
           Installed: php-common-5.4.28-34.el6.art.x86_64 (@atomic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.28-34.el6.art
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have tried sudo clean all
and then sudo yum update.

I have looked at various posts on the web and see no real resolution for me. Can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

You are using PHP 5.4.28 from another repo but trying to install php-soap from the CentOS 6 repo (which is PHP 5.3.3).

The external repo you are using for 5.4 may not have the soap package.  You can check what's available with `yum list "php-soap*"`.

If that repo doesn't have it, you can try to install the RPM from another source: http://google.com/?q=php-soap+5.4.28+rpm

Comment: I see a site with all the Soap version on. How do I download the file to the server. I have not done this before. http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/mageia/3/i586/media/core/updates/php-soap-5.4.28-1.mga3.i586.html

Comment: available soap currently on server is php-soap.x86_64 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problem with soap for php 5.6. Was installed for 5.4 by default and was need to remove previous version.

```
# rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
# yum erase php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
# rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
# yum update
# yum clean all
# yum install -y php56w php56w-opcache php56w-xml php56w-mcrypt php56w-gd php56w-devel php56w-mysql php56w-intl php56w-mbstring
```

You can substitute the version that you need. I hope this will help you

Comment: Where you say erase php-common above should it be the installed that I erase so # yum erase php-common-5.4.28-34.el6.art.x86_64     Installed: php-common-5.4.28-34.el6.art.x86_64 (@atomic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.28-34.el6.art

Comment: I am unable now to log in to plesk panel! need help urgent!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have sorted it out for my situation.
I followed AVERUN above solution to an extent as it seemed to cripple me a bit as I lost Plesk panel and sites went down. I called 1and1 to restart and run diagnostic. They did this and apache restarted and a few php extension were updated by 1 and 1.
But then I did the following as php mcrypt was now also missing

## yum install php56w-mcrypt

## yum install php56w-soap

This seems to have solved it for me thanks to the help of AVERUN and 1 and 1 also.